# Need some information with Python loop and/or repeat functions

Tags: python, loops, repeat

I am fairly new to python, I have read, searched, studied, and executed. I am having problems finding an answer to what I am trying to do. Here is what i have....

```py
 # GPIO setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.OUT)


def solenoid_on(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)  # Turn solenoid on


def solenoid_off(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)  # Turn solenoid off

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        solenoid_on(channel) #              |~ in this section, i would like to repeat X amount
        time.sleep(1)    # Sets lag time    |  of times, have a set number of "run time" say...
        solenoid_off(channel) #             |  150 times..or do i just copy and paste this block
        time.sleep(3)    # Sets run time    |  150 times? 

        print("DONE")

        GPIO.cleanup()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Thanks for the help it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look into `for` loops. One possible format will look something like: `for iteration in range( 150 ):` where everything that you want to be repeated 150 times should be under that line and indented

Comment: thank you good sir,  it is much appreciated, i just haven't found my "ah-ha" moment yet where things make sense lol, thank you for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':

try:
    for i in range(150):
        solenoid_on(channel) #              |~ in this section, i would like to repeat X amount
        time.sleep(1)    # Sets lag time    |  of times, have a set number of "run time" say...
        solenoid_off(channel) #             |  150 times..or do i just copy and paste this block
        time.sleep(3)    # Sets run time    |  150 times? 

        print("Iteration", i, " is done")

    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: I suspect that'll fail on iteration 2 due to the GPIO.cleanup() - I suspect it should be dedented out of the for loop?

Comment: I'm glad someone knows whats going on lol thank you for the help you're a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: David Waterworth....it did not fail, i set the range(4) just to test it and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below. For loop runs through it 150 times.

If you specifically need it to run X number of times, use a for loop

If you need it to work until Y happens (like some response, or time limit), use a while loop

Wasn't really sure if you wanted the try/except inside the for loop or not.

**For Loop**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        for i in range(150):
            start = time.time()
            print('Turning Solenoid', i, 'On')
            solenoid_on(channel) 
            time.sleep(1)
            print('Turning Solenoid', i, 'Off')
            solenoid_off(channel)
            time.sleep(3)
            print('Completed Solenoid', i, 'in', time.time()-start, 'seconds\n\n')

        GPIO.cleanup()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

**While Loop**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    #minutes elapsed    
    elapsed = 0
    start = time.time()
    while elapsed < 10:
        try:
            print('Turning Solenoid', i, 'On')
            solenoid_on(channel) 
            time.sleep(1)
            print('Turning Solenoid', i, 'Off')
            solenoid_off(channel)
            time.sleep(3)
            print('Completed Solenoid', i, 'in', time.time()-start, 'seconds\n\n')

            GPIO.cleanup()

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            GPIO.cleanup()

        # set elapsed minutes
        elapsed = (time.time()-start)/60
        print('Elapsed time...', elapsed, 'minutes')
```